# Using the NEW variable in trigger functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

PostgreSQL 9.4

I'm working on the following trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_inserted_row() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    --Here I need to transform the NEW trigger variable
    --to an array of values or something else that can be iterated over
    --and check each value in it

    --How can I do that?
    RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The issue is I don't know for sure what columns will be contained in `NEW` as that it might happen that some columns will be added later. To avoid rewriting the trigger any time it happens I'd like to iterate over all columns in `NEW` and perform required checking.

Is it possible?

Comment: This might give you some ideas: http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html and this: http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/ and this: http://www.tuicool.com/articles/2eiQfa